# Lightning button to update records

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, picklist

I have a component with a table, of which one of the columns is a picklist and is iterated:

```
<td data-label="Decision">
    <ui:inputSelect  class="slds-select spear-select" aura:id="selectItem" value="{!itm.wrapItem.Decision__c}" updateOn="change" >    
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.itemDecisionList}" var="stat">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!stat}" label="{!stat}" value="{!stat==itm.wrapItem.Decision__c}" />            
        </aura:iteration>    
    </ui:inputSelect>
```

And a button:  that calls out to a section in my Controller.js:

```
    changeDcn : function(component, event, helper) {
         var allItems = component.get("v.relatedItems");
         for(var i in allItems){
           var space = allItems[i];    
           //alert("Decision: " + space.wrapItem.Decision__c);
         }

         var action = component.get("c.saveDcn");
         action.setParams({"dcns":  JSON.stringify(i) });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response){
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var stat = component.get("v.itemDecisionList");
            stat.push(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.itemDecisionList", stat);
         }
       });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);

   },
```

that references the save on my Controller.apxc:

```
    @auraEnabled
   public static List<RIM_Item__c> saveDcn(String stat){
       List<RIM_Item__c> statList = (List<RIM_Item__c>) JSON.deserialize(stat, List<RIM_Item__c>.class); 
       UPDATE statList;
       RETURN statList;
   }
```

**My problem is** that I want my save button to update the records with the new picklist value, and it isn't working. Any thoughts/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

UPDATES:
**New helper being called by jsController:**

```
saveDecisions: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Getting the list from lightning component
    var contactList = component.get("v.selectedItems");
    var toastEvent = $A.get('e.force:showToast');// Initializing the toast event to show toast
    // Defining the action to save contact List ( will call the saveDcns apex controller )
    var saveAction = component.get("c.saveDcns");
    saveAction.setParams({ contactList : contactList });// setting the params to be passed to apex controller
    saveAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {// callback action on getting the response from server
        // Getting the state from response
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS') {// Getting the response from server
            var dataMap = response.getReturnValue();// Checking if the status is success
            if(dataMap.status=='success') {
                // Setting the success toast which is dismissable ( vanish on timeout or on clicking X button )
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title': 'Success!',
                    'type': 'success',
                    'mode': 'dismissable',
                    'message': dataMap.message
                });
                toastEvent.fire();   // Fire success toast event ( Show toast )  
            }
            // Checking if the status is error 
            else if(dataMap.status=='error') {
                // Setting the error toast which is dismissable ( vanish on timeout or on clicking X button )
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title': 'Error!',
                    'type': 'error',
                    'mode': 'dismissable',
                    'message': dataMap.message
                });
                // Fire error toast event ( Show toast )
                toastEvent.fire();                
            }
        }
        else {
            // Show an alert if the state is incomplete or error
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
}
```

**New apex controller:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,String> saveDcns(List<RIM_Item__c> contactList) {
    // Forming a  string map to return response
    Map<String,String> resultMap = new Map<String,String>();
    // Adding try catch for exception handling
    try {  // Updating the List
        update contactList;
        // Setting the success status and message in resultMap
        resultMap.put('status', 'success');
            resultMap.put('message', 'Updated Successfully');}
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Setting the success status and message in resultMap
        resultMap.put('status', 'error');
                    resultMap.put('message',e.getMessage());}
    // Returning the result string map
    return resultMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name doesn't match:

```
     action.setParams({"dcns":  JSON.stringify(i) });
```

---

```
public static List<RIM_Item__c> saveDcn(String stat){
```

---

You need to change one or the other so they match.

Side note: you'll want to fix the format of the parameter data, too. You're calling the server once per item, which will be inefficient, and you'll have stuff getting overwritten that you don't mean to.

Side note 2: You can pass in whole objects, there's no need to serialize/deserialize your data.

Comment: So, I originally had the apxc as     `@auraEnabled
    public static RIM_Item__c saveDcn(RIM_Item__c dcns){
        UPDATE dcns;
        RETURN dcns;
   }`                 That was correct?

Comment: @Kashona Assuming you pass in a single record, yes, that should work. I would advise passing in a list of records instead, though, since it appears you're trying to do a bulk update.

Comment: after extensive Googling, I've changed my js controller to call to the helper. I also updated my apex controller, please reference my original post as I'm going to add them to the bottom of that for formatting purposes:

Comment: These updates have resulted in a toast "Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []" -- How do I get the Ids to pass?

Comment: @Kashona You'll need to get the Id from the wrapItem, I think, in order to set the proper values. You need the ID for each record in order to make an update.